# sort column by variable name then loop in each variable

Tags: r

I am an R noob :) and this is my first post.
I have a dataset of 4k entries (`data`) describing mortality rates (`data$mortality`) by US state (`data$state`).

I want to loop through the mortality rates by state name 
for instance loop through all mortality rates in `"AK"`
something like this:

```
tbl <- table (data$State) ## table with frequency for entries at each state
```

How can I loop through all the occurrences of each state?

I don't want to specify the state name. I want to sort all states then loop through them by name:
`"AK"`, `"AL"` etc...

for instance, my table would be:

```
State   mortality 
AL  14.3
AL  18.5
AL  18.1
AL  NA
AL  NA
AK  NA
AK  17.7
AK  18
AK  15.9
AK  NA
AK  19.6
AK  17.3
AZ  15
AZ  17.1
AZ  17.1
AZ  NA
AZ  16.4
AZ  15.2
AZ  16.7
```

I can then loop through all rates in "AL" and rank them then choose a hospital name associated with each ranked mortality rate in "AL"
I can write a piece of code for each state at a time but imagine doing that for all states!

Comment: Can you post a sample (first 6 rows, etc) of the data that you're working with and a sample of the output that you would like to see?

Comment: You'll want to look at `by`, `aggregate` and `tapply`.

Comment: Have a look at the `data.table` package

Comment: If you want to loop through something, you probably aren't thinking in the way problems are usually solved in R. At best you describe the problem you want to solve.

Comment: Please make an effort to format your text in a nicer and more readable way in the future (me and @Frank just did it for you). If you don't know how, read the [markdown editing help](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) or press the orange question mark at the top right corner of the text field.

Comment: What data do you have about the hospitals that allows you to specify which hospital get applied?

Comment: @Christian my data includes a listing of all hospitals in all the states with records on heart attack mortalities. I want to rank the hospitals by lowest to highest mortality rates then generate a data.frame with the hospital names (with low mortality rates) by state name

Comment: I think you mis-sorted the states. AK should be before AL, alphabetically, right?

Comment: Also you need to refer to the variable for states with consistent capitalization, either "State" or "state", in the code. I tried to make it consistent but @mjk disagreed.

Comment: @Frank, yes "AK" is first after sorting and "s" in States is capital. Thx :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a data.table solution, as suggested in a comment:

```
require(data.table)
DT <- data.table(hospID=1:nrow(data),data)
DT[,r:=rank(mortality,na.last='keep'),by=State]
```

Then run `DT` to see the result:

```
    hospID State mortality   r
 1:      1    AL      14.3 1.0
 2:      2    AL      18.5 3.0
 3:      3    AL      18.1 2.0
 4:      4    AL        NA  NA
 5:      5    AL        NA  NA
 6:      6    AK        NA  NA
 7:      7    AK      17.7 3.0
 8:      8    AK      18.0 4.0
 9:      9    AK      15.9 1.0
10:     10    AK        NA  NA
11:     11    AK      19.6 5.0
12:     12    AK      17.3 2.0
13:     13    AZ      15.0 1.0
14:     14    AZ      17.1 5.5
15:     15    AZ      17.1 5.5
16:     16    AZ        NA  NA
17:     17    AZ      16.4 3.0
18:     18    AZ      15.2 2.0
```

Look at `?rank` to see different ways of handling ties and `NA` values.

If you want to sort on the rank, you can do that with `DT[order(State,r)]`. The data.table package also allows for a key -- a vector of columns on which the data.table is sorted automatically. There are other benefits to setting a key as well that you can read about in a data.table tutorial or the FAQ.

Answer (score 0):

To sort by col 'a':

```
x = data.frame(a = sample(LETTERS, 10), b = runif(10))
x = x[order(x[, 'a']), ]
print(x)

4  B 0.8030872
9  C 0.3754850
7  D 0.8670409
5  G 0.1278583
3  J 0.9161972
6  N 0.7159080
8  R 0.5340525
2  S 0.2903496
10 T 0.5466612
1  V 0.9187505
```